# Postman returning 404 for rest API

Tags: java, spring, rest, postman

Postman is returning a 404, My path is correct, and my ports are correct. XAMPP is on.
the error I am getting is shown in the following picture
[image]

the Controller method I am trying to test is

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/hateoas", produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
    public Resources<Breweries> getBreweryHATEOAS() {

        List<Breweries> allBreweries = service.getAllBreweries();

        for (Breweries b : allBreweries) {

            int breweryId = b.getId();//getBreweryByID();
            Link selfLink = linkTo(this.getClass()).slash(breweryId).withSelfRel();
            b.add(selfLink);
            linkTo(methodOn(this.getClass()).getBreweryByID(breweryId));
        }
        Link link = linkTo(this.getClass()).withSelfRel();
        Resources<Breweries> result = new Resources<Breweries>(allBreweries, link);
        return result;

    }
```

the request mapping on the outside of the controller is

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/breweries")
@SessionAttributes("breweries")
public class BreweriesController {
```

the file name is

[image]

Comment: Please do not include pictures in your question. Just use the formatting

Comment: Try to remove `Assignment4` from the URL

Comment: did you try the path `http://localhost:8080/breweries/hateoas`? 404 with Spring means you don't even have such a path on your application if your controller is on proper location based on project structure, the  path is not present in your application.

Comment: please share the yaml file as well, that will help in identifying the correct path.
The problem is the path. you should be acually be able ton  figure it out

Comment: @am0awad that still causes a 404

Comment: @ImtiazeA ya i tried that, and that doesnt work

Comment: Instead of the class location, show the whole project structure.